# Nothing happens when i click on the tick box (submit)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, x-editable

I've used xeditable in multiple places in my application and everything works just fine although in one particular place, nothing happens when i click on the tick box:

[image: example screenshot]

(ideally its about to trigger the onaftersave function here)

```
<span editable-text="label.yellowColor" e-rows="1" e-cols="5" onaftersave="updateLabelName($data)" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">{{label.yellowColor || '...'}}</span>
```

It would be great to get input on the above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind the text to a variable in the scope with `ng-model` ? This way you could display it everywhere AND access it all the more throughout your program.

Comment: thanks @sylordis ! thing is, when i click on the click/submit, nothing happens in the sense that the tick mark continues to stay

Comment: What are you calling "tick mark" ? the button with a check mark ? Can you explain a little more, maybe with the structure of the form and how the element you put as a screenshot is supposed to behave, please ?